# How can I set up using a different version of Python from the OS?

Tags: software-installation, python

my OS (Ubuntu 14.04) uses an older version 2.7.6 of Python as `/usr/bin/python` which points to `/usr/bin/python2.7` I installed a new version 2.7.9 of python as `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.

In my own shell,

- how can I make all python scripts with shebang to use the new python? Does use `#!/usr/bin/env python` as shebang solve the problem? How shall I make it work?
- Can I also make the command `python` be the new one?

while letting my OS still use its original older one?

Comment: not yet., @Mark

Comment: Ah, your updated question makes things easier. Many people add `/usr/local/bin` to the beginning of their search path so that they can run newer versions of system programs. If this is OK with you, run `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python`, then edit your own `~/.bash_profile` to include a line that says `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`. Logout, login again. Run `python --version` to verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set things up so that `python` gets you the new version but everyone else, including the standard OS programs, will get the original:

- choose a directory to hold your personal programs (or symlinks to them).  This could be `$HOME/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, whatever you like. Create it if it doesn't exist. I'll use `$HOME/bin` in this example.
- Edit your `~/.profile`. On Ubuntu 14.04, it likely already contains a line that says `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`, which will put this directory at the front of your search path. If not, add that line.
- run `ln -s /usr/local/bin/python2.7 $HOME/bin/python`
- logout, login, type `which python` to verify that the shell is finding the (symlink) python in your `$HOME/bin` directory. Type `python --version` to verify that you're getting the new version.

You're already doing a good thing by having your scripts start with the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` rather than `#!/usr/bin/python`. The `env` command will look through your search path to find `python`.

Comment: with `#!/usr/bin/env python`, what do I do outside the script to use the new python automatically? Just add the path of the new python to my PATH?

Comment: You add the directory that contains the new python (or contains a symlink to the new python) to the front of PATH. PATH contains just directories, each separated by a colon.

Comment: will my OS still use its original and old python?

Comment: +1..good use of `$HOME/bin`

Comment: @Tim It should. If you do `cd /usr/bin; grep python *`, you can see that every system program there that needs python uses the full pathname: `#!/usr/bin/python`, `#!/usr/bin/python3`, etc. Operating system vendors fully expect people will have their own private versions of things like python coexisting with the system versions.

Answer (score 1):

***how can I make all python scripts with shebang to use the new python?***

Use the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`

***Can I also make the command python be the new one?***

You can name the compiled Python something else e.g. `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` and then directly call the binary by full path or create an alias like

```
alias python2.7='/usr/local/bin/python2.7'
```

and put it in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks. (1) sorry I messed up the directory for my new python. see my edit. (2) I heard that Ubuntu 14.04 must use its default python, and can't use the new python I installed. So if I make `/usr/bin/python` point to my new python, will that make my OS not work properly?

Comment: @Tim: Answer edited..hope its clear now

Comment: Whether it is allowed to replace the default python with newer python, see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/103772/how-to-update-ubuntus-python-with-latest-version-from-source, and http://askubuntu.com/questions/597855/good-to-replace-my-python-2-7-6-with-python-2-7-9. From the first link, I understand that it is not allowe, and Ubuntu needs the default old python.

Comment: @Tim: Now i get whats your real query is..yes, its true that many python modules will be unavailable and also the programs depending on those modules won't simply work..your best bet would be to name it something else like `/usr/local/bin/python2.9` and then directly call the binary by full path or create an alias like `alias python2.9=/usr/local/bin/python2.9`

Comment: @Tim: you can use `alias` or use as other answer pointed out to symlinked to `$HOME/bin` ..it will make sure no system program will use this one..normally those programs use full path to the binary, if some program is not using it then they will search through the `PATH` which will not include your `$HOME/bin`..

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you may also use [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), it allows you to use different python versions inside.